# How to isolate incoming application requests with virtual hosts using springBootApplication tag on Open Liberty?

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

When using the enterpriseApplication tag, I first define the virtual host like:

```
<virtualHost id="mysitevirtualhost" name="mysitevirtualhost" allowFromEndpointRef="defaultHttpEndpoint">
        <hostAlias>mysitevirtualhost.com:443</hostAlias>
 </virtualHost>
```

And then we add it on the web-bnd:

```
<enterpriseApplication id="App-app" location="App.ear"> 
         <web-ext context-root="App" moduleName="App-develop-SNAPSHOT"/>
         <web-bnd moduleName="App-develop-SNAPSHOT">
            <virtual-host name="mysitevirtualhost" />
        </web-bnd>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

How can we accomplish the same using the springBootApplication tag?

```
<springBootApplication location="App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar">
        <applicationArgument>--server.servlet.context-path=/App/</applicationArgument>
</springBootApplication>
```

I tried using the generic application tag like:

```
<application type="spring" location="App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar">
    <applicationArgument>--server.servlet.context-path=/App/</applicationArgument>
    <web-bnd moduleName="App-develop-SNAPSHOT">
        <virtual-host name="mysitevirtualhost" />
    </web-bnd>
</application>
```

But looks like the moduleName is not App-develop-SNAPSHOT, on the logs shows as 0-0, and I tried that as well but no success.